# ImportError: cannot import name OptionsTRANUSDialog

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a strange problem : ImportError: cannot import name OptionsTRANUSDialog
In the file OptionsTRANUSDialog, I can get my checked_list by this method :

```
    model = self.scenarios.model()
    checked_indexes = model.match(model.index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole,QtCore.Qt.Checked, -1,QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive)

    for index in checked_indexes:
        item = model.itemFromIndex(index)
        item_text = item.text()
        self.checked_list.append(item_text)

    if self.checked_list != [] :
        dialog = LaunchTRANUSDialog(parent=self)
        dialog.show()
        result = dialog.exec_()
```

I want to use this checked_list in another file(launch_tranus_dialog), so I put the import in this file :

```
from .Options_TRANUS_dialog import OptionsTRANUSDialog
```

And when I execute I get this error :
ImportError: cannot import name OptionsTRANUSDialog

I really don't understand this import error.

Could you help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: your file `Options_TRANUS_dialog` should  reside in the same directory where your are implementing the import statement then only import statement will work otherwise you have to give the path of `Options_TRANUS_dialog` file in PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: Hello, my file reside in the same directory as the file when I put the import statement. I will try with the path and guess what the result. Thanks.

Comment: @Ammoun. The other comment is wrong. If the `Options_TRANUS_dialog` file wasn't found, you would see a different error: "No module named Options_TRANUS_dialog". So please ignore the advice about changing your `PYTHONPATH`. The error is actually telling you that the module exists, but does not contain a class called `OptionsTRANUSDialog`. So the actual name must be different. Is it a pyuic file? If so, the class would probably be called `Ui_OptionsTRANUSDialog`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your advice . Here is a copy of my class :FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Options_TRANUS_dialog_base.ui'))
class OptionsTRANUSDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):def __init__(self,project,parent=None):
        super(OptionsTRANUSDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)